# Find repeated sentences within text

Tags: python, pandas, counter, similarity

I would like to know how I could find similarity within the same sentence.
I have a list of sentences like these:

```
my_list=["do you want pizza for dinner? Do you want pizza for dinner?", "I like pizza", "I have no money I have no money"]
```

I would like to create a pandas dataframe where, if a sentence is repeated within the same, I assign 1, otherwise 0.

Something like this:

```
Text                                                              Repeated?
do you want pizza for dinner? Do you want pizza for dinner?            1
I like pizza                                                           0
I have no money I have no money                                        1
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
from collections import Counter


my_list = dict(Counter(my_list.split()))
for i in sorted(my_list.keys()):
    print ('"'+i+'" is repeated '+str(my_list[i])+' time.')
```

Then counting how many words there are in total and how many unique words there are in total in that sentence. But I think it would be not good as coding.
Do you know if there is another way to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression for the task ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SuuJFo/1)):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

my_list=["do you want pizza for dinner? Do you want pizza for dinner?", "I like pizza", "I have no money I have no money"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': my_list})

r = re.compile(r'(.+)\s*\1$', flags=re.I)
df['Repeated'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: bool(r.match(x))).astype(int) 
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                Text  Repeated
0  do you want pizza for dinner? Do you want pizz...         1
1                                       I like pizza         0
2                    I have no money I have no money         1
```